# SQL: Find Quintiles using Partition By

Tags: sql, hive

I have a transactions table `t1` that looks like this:

```
store_id.   cust_id.   amount
100         1000        1.00
100         1000        2.05
100         1000        3.15
100         2000        5.00
100         2000        6.00
200         3000       16.00
200         3000       60.00
200         1000        6.00
300         1000        8.05
300         1000       15.15
```

I also have a reference table `t2` that pairs stores with one or more industry peers:

```
store_id.   peer_id
100         200
200         100
300         300
```

Here's the code to generate the tables above:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TABLE t1(
    store_id int,
    cust_id int,
    amount float,
);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(100,1000,1.00);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(100,1000,2.05);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(100,1000,3.15);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(100,2000,5.00);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(100,2000,6.00);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(200,3000,16.00);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(200,3000,60.00);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(200,1000,6.00);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(300,1000,8.05);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(300,1000,15.15);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;
CREATE TABLE t2(
    store_id int,
    peer_id int
);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(100,200);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(200,100);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(300,300);
```

I would like to assign each customer_id to a quintile based on their total spend at a particular store **and** that store's peers. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    a.cust_id
    , b.store_id
    , b.peer_id
    , NTILE(5) OVER(PARTITION BY b.store_id, b.peer_id ORDER BY sum(a.amount) DESC) as quintile 
    ,sum(a.amount) as total
FROM t1 a
LEFT JOIN t2 b
ON a.store_id=b.store_id
GROUP BY a.cust_id, b.store_id, b.peer_id;
```

However, this code does not work because it assigns each customer to multiple quintiles. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Why are you partitioning (and grouping) by store And peer? What do you believe it accomplishes?  (I believe it's an error, but I'm trying to avoid making an assumption.)  Also, do you want one result for each customer, or one result for each customer/store combination?

Comment: @MatBailie: yes, likely an error. What I'm trying to do is partition first by store_id and then by peer_id in order to identify purchases at either a particular store or its peers. Suppose I shop at stores 100 and 200. Assume store 200 is a peer of store 100 (but not necessarily the reverse). Then, when I compute the quintiles for store 100, I would like to include both of my purchases at store 100 and store 200.

Comment: Partioning by both keeps each store/peer separate from the others (giving you separate ntiles for each store/peer combination). You want to combine the results, not separate them. The answer below doesn't combine them, by not separating them. (amongst other changes)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need aggregation:

```
select t2.store_id, t1.customer_id, sum(t1.amount),
       ntile(5) over (partition by t1.store_id order by sum(t1.amount))
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.store_id = t2.peer_id
group by t1.customer_id, t2.store_id;
```

Note:  This assumes that a store is its own peer.  You need additional logic if that is not the case.

EDIT:

The most efficient modification would be to make a store its own peer.  You can also use this logic:

```
select t2.store_id, t1.customer_id, sum(t1.amount),
       ntile(5) over (partition by t1.store_id order by sum(t1.amount))
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.store_id = t2.peer_id or t2.store_id = t1.store_id
group by t1.customer_id, t2.store_id;
```

But the `or` will kill performance.

So:

```
select t1.store_id, t1.customer_id, sum(t1.amount),
       ntile(5) over (partition by t1.store_id order by sum(t1.amount))
from t1 join
     (select store_id, peer_id
      from t2
      union all
      select distinct store_id, store_id
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.store_id = t2.peer_id or t2.store_id = t1.store_id
group by t1.customer_id, t2.store_id;
```

Note:  This assumes that all stores are in `t2`.  The second subquery just needs to get the additional rows -- which can use `t1` or another table as well.

Comment: Thank you. How would you modify it if a store is not its own peer?

Comment: @caerus Either change the data in t2 so that a store IS its own peer, or fake it using `(select * from t2 UNION ALL select id, id FROM store_table) as t2` in place of `t2`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff thank you, but won't these queries throw an error if `t1.store_id` is not in the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: @caerus It should have `t2.store_id` in the `SELECT` clause -and- in the `PARTITION BY`.  Also, the last query shouldn't have the `OR` condition in the join predicate.